# How to get a parent routes model from inside controller action?

Tags: ember.js

Inside my route for "appointments" below I can reach up and get the model for the parent "day"

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {                                          
    this.resource("day", { path: "/day/:day" }, function() {              
        this.resource("appointments", { path: "/appointments" }, function() {
            this.route("new", { path: "/:appointment_start/new" });
            this.route("edit", { path: "/:appointment_id/edit" });        
        });                                                               
    });                                                                   
});
```

But when I'm deep inside the new or edit routes, how can I reach up (from within the actions handler) and grab the parent "day" model like I did in the route?

```
App.AppointmentsEditController = Ember.Controller.extend({                
    actions: {
        updateAppointment: function(appointment) {
            var day = this.get('??');
        }
    }
});
```

**Update**

The final controller code now looks like this

```
App.AppointmentsEditController = Ember.Controller.extend({       
    needs: 'day',         
    actions: {
        updateAppointment: function(appointment) {
            var day = this.get('controllers.day');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toran - sorry to add this as an extra answer, I can't comment yet - yes, it should work for free. You can access `controllers.post` from within the `actions` block like this:

```
var postController = this.get('controllers.post')
```

Comment: thank you! this worked as you suggested (I just needed to add the needs day line to get it 100%)

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do this, but instead trying to get the parent Appointment rather than the day within the AppointmentEdit controller. I tried using this.get('controllers.appointments') but I get an array of appointments rather than the specific one I'm editing. Could you advise as to how to get appointment being edited? I can get array of all appointments *within the controller* using the above method. I can get the params.appointment_id *within the route*. But I can't figure out how to get the appointment itself within either.

Comment: *Fixed above by saving array to a controller property, then grabbing that property from the route and going to the specific param.appointment_id index. Seems overly complicated...Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 2):

There is simple way to do it. In `AppointmentsEditController` add

```
needs: "day"
```

Then you can access to `day` controller via `this.get('controllers.day')`.

I always use something like this:

```
App.CommentsControler = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: "post",
    postBinding: "controllers.post",
    ...
    postName: function() {
        return this.post.name;
    }.property("post.name")
})
```

Take a look of this article http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

I hope this help :)

Comment: In order to use the `day` controller within the comments controller, you have to use `this.get('controllers.day');` instead of `this.controllers.day`, as otherwise it will not recognize what what controllers is.